# Random uniform distribution of points with minimum spacing

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to generate the coordinates of a set of points in a 2d space that are randomly uniformly spaced, but not too close to each other.

I started out with `np.random.uniform`, to generate n x 2 values (x and y coordinates), then sifting through the list of coordinates using two nested for-loops over all coordinates to remove points that are too close and randomly place them somewhere else:

```
# Generate xy coordinates for the grafting points
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=self.rng_seed)
    coordinates = rng.uniform(high=(self.box_size[0], self.box_size[1]), size=(n_chains, 2))

for count in range(0, self.max_overlap_iter):
    moved_bead = False
    # Search for overlapping beads by looping over the list doubly
    for id_i, coord_i in enumerate(coordinates):
        for id_j, coord_j in enumerate(coordinates):
            if not id_i == id_j and np.sqrt(sum((coord_i - coord_j)**2)) < self.bead_size:
                # Move the second point
                coordinates[id_j] = rng.uniform(high=(self.box_size[0], self.box_size[1]), size=2)
                moved_bead = True
    if not moved_bead:
        break
```

After a point has been moved to a new random location, it has to go through the outer loop again because it might still overlap.

The problem is that this becomes really slow when the density of points is high enough, because the probability that some points 'overlap' skyrockets. I had to build in a maximum number of iterations because of that, but that is obviously not a solution to my problem.

Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How important is it that these points are "random" - i.e. Would it affect your application to generate your points on some kind of grid with a Gaussian shift applied to each bead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a Poisson-disk point set generator algorithm that can generate non-maximal point sets and runs in linear time, using some ideas I got from other algorithms.

Thanks to @Kamil of course for giving me the term "Poisson-disk point set" to Google ;)

It can be found here: https://github.com/Compizfox/MDBrushGenerators/blob/master/PoissonDiskGenerator.py

Comment: @RahatZaman My apologies, I reorganized the repositories. I fixed the link again.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried utilizing Poisson-Disc sampling algorithm?

I think it might be what you are looking for.

[Python implementation](https://scipython.com/blog/poisson-disc-sampling-in-python/)

[image]

[Jason Davies Poisson-Disc Sampling](https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/)

[Mike Bostock implementation in Javascript](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/19168c663618b7f07158)

Below is the code in case it is deleted

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var sample = poissonDiscSampler(width, height, 10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.timer(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var s = sample();
    if (!s) return true;
    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", s[0])
        .attr("cy", s[1])
        .attr("r", 0)
      .transition()
        .attr("r", 2);
  }
});

// Based on https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/
function poissonDiscSampler(width, height, radius) {
  var k = 30, // maximum number of samples before rejection
      radius2 = radius * radius,
      R = 3 * radius2,
      cellSize = radius * Math.SQRT1_2,
      gridWidth = Math.ceil(width / cellSize),
      gridHeight = Math.ceil(height / cellSize),
      grid = new Array(gridWidth * gridHeight),
      queue = [],
      queueSize = 0,
      sampleSize = 0;

  return function() {
    if (!sampleSize) return sample(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);

    // Pick a random existing sample and remove it from the queue.
    while (queueSize) {
      var i = Math.random() * queueSize | 0,
          s = queue[i];

      // Make a new candidate between [radius, 2 * radius] from the existing sample.
      for (var j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        var a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random(),
            r = Math.sqrt(Math.random() * R + radius2),
            x = s[0] + r * Math.cos(a),
            y = s[1] + r * Math.sin(a);

        // Reject candidates that are outside the allowed extent,
        // or closer than 2 * radius to any existing sample.
        if (0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height && far(x, y)) return sample(x, y);
      }

      queue[i] = queue[--queueSize];
      queue.length = queueSize;
    }
  };

  function far(x, y) {
    var i = x / cellSize | 0,
        j = y / cellSize | 0,
        i0 = Math.max(i - 2, 0),
        j0 = Math.max(j - 2, 0),
        i1 = Math.min(i + 3, gridWidth),
        j1 = Math.min(j + 3, gridHeight);

    for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j) {
      var o = j * gridWidth;
      for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i) {
        if (s = grid[o + i]) {
          var s,
              dx = s[0] - x,
              dy = s[1] - y;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius2) return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  function sample(x, y) {
    var s = [x, y];
    queue.push(s);
    grid[gridWidth * (y / cellSize | 0) + (x / cellSize | 0)] = s;
    ++sampleSize;
    ++queueSize;
    return s;
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looked very promising at first but I don't think I can use it because I need to be able to specify the average density. (I forgot to mention that in my question.)

I don't think you can do that with Poisson-Disc sampling; you can only specify `r`, the minimum distance between points.

Comment: @Compizfox nothing prevents you from defining a function that will take a density as an input and compute required `r`. it is simple: `r = sqrt(PI/density)`. The formula gives slighty too big radius but it should be ok for higher densities

Comment: Varying `r` is not the same, as this will change the minimum distance between points. I want to vary the point density independently of `r`. In other words, the Poisson-Disk point set I generate should not (always) be maximal. With this info about Poisson-Disk point sets though, I think I can come up with some more efficient algorithm for generating non-maximal point sets than the 'brute force' algorithm that I have now. Thanks!